# IMAP4 server for .NET

Tags: .net, imap, mail-server

Are there any free (non-GPL) libraries for .NET that provide IMAP4 server side functionality?

E.g. handles the socket level and message handshaking so that an IMAP4 client (such as outlook) can retrieve, read, edit and/or delete messages.

I am not trying to connect to an IMAP4 server, I'd like the assistance to implement one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I'm answering my own question, but after yet more searching I think I may have found something matching my needs:

[NMail](http://nmailserver.sourceforge.net/index.php/Main_Page)

Features

- NMail is a 100% .net application.
- A Windows installer and setup wizard.
- ASP.net Webmail.
- An ASP.net administration site.

IMAP Server Features

- Support for ACLs.
- NTLM authentication (Secure Password Authentication (SPA) under Outlook and Outlook Express).
- Support for SSL/TLS encryption.
- SASL plain authentication support (when using an encrypted session).

SMTP Server Features

- Support for SSL/TLS encryption.
- Flexible API for filtering and altering messages. E.g. To remove spam or to rewrite addresses, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have tried Indy (previously a set of Delphi components) - although I am not sure if they do IMAP4 as their web page is a bit blank, as is their CodePlex hub. Go to [their website](http://indy-project.org). Other than that I'm not sure - even [Google](http://google.co.uk/search?q=c#+imap4+server) only shows clients.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Lumisoft Mail Server](http://www.lumisoft.ee/lswww/ENG/Products/Mail_Server/mail_index_eng.aspx?type=info). The license is FREEWARE.

General:

```
* SMTP/POP3/IMAP4/WebMail
* IP access filtering
* User mailbox size limit
* Supports XML or MSSQL databases
* Nice GUI for administation
* Well commented source code included
```

SMTP:

```
* All basic smtp features
*  Supports multiple domains
*  Supports multiple e-address for one mailbox
*  Supports aliases(Mailing lists). Supports public and private 
   (needs authentication) lists.
*  Supports email routing. eg *ivar* pattern routes all addresses containing 
   ivar to specified mailbox or remote address
*  SMTP AUTH (LOGIN CRAM-MD5) (supported authentication types)
*  SMTP SIZE, PIPELINING, 8BITMIME, CHUNCKING support
*  SMTP custom message filters
*  Relay can be controlled by IP access or authentication
```

POP3:

```
* All basic pop3 features
* APOP command for secure authentication
* POP3 AUTH (LOGIN CRAM-MD5) (supported authentication types)
* POP3 remote accounts
```

WebMail (ASP.NET):

```
* Standalone webmail, can be used any with IMAP based mailserver
* Supports XML or MSSQL databases
* Multiple UI languages
```